# ошибка в скрипте который запрещает повторно регаться на одно имя

Tags: php, html

```
    define ('HOST',       'localhost');
    define ('USER',       'root');
    define ('PASS',       '12345');
    define ('DB',         '*****');

    $connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

    if ( !$connect ) die('Ошибка подключения к БД');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $login                         = $_POST['username'];
    $password                      = $_POST['password'];
    $r_password                    = $_POST['rpass'];
}


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username =     $login ");


        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);


        if($user_data['username'] != ($query2)){
            echo "Vi zaregani";
            $check = true;
                if ($check == true){
                    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO signup username) VALUES ('$login')");
                }

        }
        else{
            echo "NET";
        }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($password == $r_password){
        //$password = md5($password);
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO signup (username, password) VALUES ('$login','$password')");       
    }
    }
```

Пытался написать скрипт не додумался ХЭЛП

Comment: $user_data['username'] и $query2 нельзя сравнивать, так возвращает объект mysqli_result либо false http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: сравнивайте логин из формы $_POST['username'] и $user_data['username'] из базки